# Setting ToolTips for a asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I want to add a tooltip on a button in asp.net web form.And i want to add it programaticaly.I want to set the tooltip string in the code.Not the design.How can i do this?

Comment: I tried it with windows form and i did it.But i was unable to do it in a web form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
 btntooltip.ToolTip = "Your String/ToolTip";
```

Here `btntooltip` is the `ID` of `Button`.

Comment: Can i do without clicking the button? I want to get the string when mouse over the button

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
mybtn.Attributes.Add("ToolTip","myToolTip");
```